# Dynamic data validated drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA but I don’t mind using something else!

I have a table with 2 columns

[image]

Col A - Heading "RP" with 20 rows begining with "Rept Pd 1" down to "Rept Pd 20"
Col B - Heading "Claims Months", each cell a data vlidated list "0 Months" to "9 Months".

A seperate cell with "Total Months".

Background: Above table is to split reporting for a project into claims months. Maximum possible number of reporting periods (RP) is 20 and minimum is 1. Claims months can range from 0 Months to 9 Months.  The total number of Months is hard keyed in, based on the figure in Total Months the ‘Claims Month’ cells for each ‘Rept Period’ should list in a drop down the number of possible Months.

E.g. If the Total Months were 24 and I were to select the Claims Months for ‘Rept Period 1’ to 20 months then ‘Rept Period 2’ should give me a list between 0 Months and 4 Months. If I selected 1 Month for 'Rept Pd 2' then drop down option for claims months for 'Rept Pd 3 should be 0 Months to 3 months and so on.

Hope that makes sense!

Many thanks

Comment: There is no simple way to do this as presented.  A couple of pointers: doing math on cells with numbers and text "3 months" is very difficult.  You will do better to use numbers only.  If the input for the months does not have to be a list (i.e. a dropdown), you can use the whole number part of Data Validation and specify a min=0 and max=(24-running total of all hours).  Then you just need to create the helper column with the running total.  This won't limit input via the drop down, but it will reject bad entries.

Answer (score 0):

Byron is right that you should limit the selections to the numbers only. I'll add some extra steps for if you ***really*** want to have the " months" included, but this makes the whole thing even more difficult and space consuming.

What you will need to do is:

1) Assuming you have the Total Months value is in J1, and that the individual Claim Months are specified in Column I, add this formula `=J1-SUM(I:I)` to another cell in the same worksheet (I'll assume K1 is used). NOTE: The Total Months & the Claim Month selections should **NOT** be in the same column.

2) Fill enough rows of one column with this formula: `=IF(ROW()-1<=K$1, ROW()-1, "")` so that you cover the largest possible Total value. Ex. if you'll never have a Total Months>100, the formula should be in rows 1-100. I'll assume you use column L, so adjust accordingly.

3) In another, out-of-the-way cell add the formula `=COUNT(L:L)`. I'll assume you use N1.

4) You now need to create a named range. To do that, go to the Formulas portion of the ribbon and click "Name Manager". In the window that opens, click "New". Add any name that suits your purposes (no spaces or special characters, except underscores), set "Scope" to the worksheet you're on, and in "Refers to:" enter this formula `=OFFSET($L$1, 0, 0, $N$1, 1)`. Add a comment if you like, and then click "OK".

5) Highlight the rows that you want to use for the Claim Months values and open the Data Validation window. Select "List" in the "Allow" field, and in the "Source" field type `=` and hit F3. In the "Paste Name" window that appears select the Named Range we created and click "OK". Click "OK" in the Data Validation window as well.

**Optional**

6) Add this formula `=IF(L1="", "", CONCATENATE(L1, " months))` to the column next to the one we added formulas to in Step 2. Drag that formula to cover the same rows we used in Step 2. I'll assume Column M is used for this formula

7) Adjust the formula in the Named Range we created in Step 4, so that `$L$1` is replaced with `$M$1`

8) In another column (I'll use column H) add this formula `=IF(I2="", "", VALUE(LEFT(I2, LEN(I2)-7)))` and have this formula appear next to each Claim Month selection cell.

9) Update the formula from Step 1 to replace `I:I` with `H:H`

You should be set.